# Why doesn't Array#delete remove an element from my array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

To practice working with arrays and hashes I use a fun lotto app. Could someone please explain to me why `result.delete(i)` deleted the whole `result` array? Isn't is suppose to delete just THAT element and return the rest of the array?( using `result - [i]` works as intended):

```
for i in 1..number_of_balls do    # taking each possible ball
  results.each do |result|        # going through results
    if result.include?(i)         # find result that contains that ball
      #result.delete(i)           # delete itself from the result
      matched_numbers[i]<< result - [i] 
    end 
  end
end
```

Here are my inputs:

```
number_of_balls = 49 
results = [[3,11,12,14,41,43,13],[8,33,36,37,39,41,9], [1,6,23,24,27,39‌​,34],
           [3,9,10,13,20,4‌​3,34], [5,14,21,31,34‌​,47,45],[8,20,21,25,‌​31,41,33],
           [18,25,28,‌​33,36,42,7],[7,16,17‌​,31,40,48,26],[5,10,‌​23,27,37,38,33],
           [4,1‌​5,30,37,46,48,3], [7,‌​9,21,33,38,42,45], [1‌​1,17,19,20,36,43,9],‌​
           [7,14,17,20,37,47,34‌​],[25,28,29,30,35,44‌​,3],[8,18,36,39,41,4‌​7,31],
           [9,12,13,14,44‌​,48,18],[4,14,18,40,‌​43,44,5], [13,16,18,3‌​4,35,36,26],
           [11,23,2‌​5,28,29,36,27]]
```

Desired output:

```
    [[11, 12, 14, 41, 43, 13], [9, 10, 13, 20, 43, 34], [4, 15, 30, 37, 46, 48],
     [25, 28, 29, 30, 35, 44], [4, 19, 33, 34, 48, 39], [4, 9, 10, 11, 43, 46],
     [5, 6, 33, 38, 39, 8],    [2, 7, 21, 22, 30, 33],  [1, 19, 31, 32, 47, 37], 
     [17, 20, 30, 35, 48, 26]]
```

Comment: can you provide the inputs you used so we can reproduce the code, and also the desired result based on those inputs. And `delete` actually deletes all the element in the array that matches `i`.

Comment: can you show the desired output?

Comment: no, keep the subarray without 3 in it. That's what current solution does. `.delete(i)` is supposed to do just that: keep array without `i` in it. I may not understand what objets I am dealing with in `.each` loop?

Comment: I still have no idea what you are trying to do. Can you add some details? maybe simplify the inputs and walk me through the process.

Comment: If you're going through all the possible balls and deleting results that include them then it makes sense that the whole results array will be deleted.  What am I missing?

Comment: what I want to do is in this snippet of code save only the result that matches a number from 1-49 (result will include the number itself), but without that number. so, instead of saving an array of 7 numbers (result) I will save an array of 6 numbers (result - number itself). If you compare `results` subarrays with corresponding *output* subarray you will the number 3 is missing.

Comment: @jcm this is only part of the code. I don't understand why `result.delete(i)` does not save altered array...

Comment: Because in your code *i* matches an Integer, not an Array.

Comment: @CodeGnome I want to thank you for providing refactored example. I study by myself and your example is invaluable for me. Your explanation of why the code does not work, made me thinking differently and I solved another problem. just thought I would mention this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Your code doesn't work because you're incorrectly comparing objects. You would be better served by using a different data structure. For example, using a Hash that keys off of your ball values simplifies things a lot.

### Why Your Code Doesn't Work

Your current code doesn't work because the variable *i* in your code is an Integer, not an Array. As a result, the [Array#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-delete) method doesn't match anything when performing its equality check. Consider the following minimal example:

```
# Define a simplified array of arrays.
arrays = [[1, 2, 3]]
#=> [[1, 2, 3]]

# Doesn't delete anything because there's no match. This is correct
# behavior, since `1 == [1, 2, 3] #=> false`.
arrays.delete 1
#=> nil

# Deletes the specified array
arrays.delete [1, 2, 3]
#=> [1, 2, 3]

# Arrays is now empty, as expected.
arrays
#=> []
```

### Refactored Example

The following provides a method for storing matching draws into a Hash object. The hash keys are the possible ball values.

```
# Your sample data reformatted.
number_of_balls = 49 
results = [
  [3,11,12,14,41,43,13],
  [8,33,36,37,39,41,9],
  [1,6,23,24,27,39,34],
  [3,9,10,13,20,43,34],
  [5,14,21,31,34,47,45],
  [8,20,21,25,31,41,33],
  [18,25,28,33,36,42,7],
  [7,16,17,31,40,48,26],
  [5,10,23,27,37,38,33],
  [4,15,30,37,46,48,3],
  [7,9,21,33,38,42,45],
  [11,17,19,20,36,43,9],
  [7,14,17,20,37,47,34],
  [25,28,29,30,35,44,3],
  [8,18,36,39,41,47,31],
  [9,12,13,14,44,48,18],
  [4,14,18,40,43,44,5],
  [13,16,18,34,35,36,26],
  [11,23,25,28,29,36,27],
]

# Returns a Hash of draws matching each available ball.
def matched_draws avail_balls, seqs_drawn 
  draws = {}
  (1..avail_balls).each do |key|
     draws[key] = seqs_drawn.select { |ary| ary.include? key }
  end 
  draws
end

# Invoke using your existing variable names.
h = matched_draws number_of_balls, results
```

### Sample Results

The Hash allows you to show all draws that contain a given ball value. Note that the value may be an empty array if no draws matched.

```
h[1]
#=> [[1, 6, 23, 24, 27, 39, 34]]

h[49]
#=> []
```